# Using R package ggmap with Google Directions API token

Tags: r, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ggmap

I'm using ggmap's "route" function to plot driving directions using Google's Driving Directions API. I may need to exceed the 2,500 daily API limit. I know that to exceed that threshold, I'll have to pay the $0.50/1000 hits fee and sign up for a Google Developers API token. However, I don't see any parameters in the ggmap library or route function that allow me to enter my token and key information so that I can exceed the threshold. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I've written the package [**googleway**](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/googleway) to access google maps API where you can specify your token key

For example

```
library(googlway)

key <- "your_api_key"
google_directions(origin = "MCG, Melbourne",
                  destination = "Flinders Street Station, Melbourne",
                  key = key,
                  simplify = F) ## use simplify = T to return a data.frame

[1] "{"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
[2] "   \"geocoded_waypoints\" : ["                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
[3] "      {"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
[4] "         \"geocoder_status\" : \"OK\","                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
[5] "         \"partial_match\" : true,"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
[6] "         \"place_id\" : \"ChIJIdtrbupC1moRMPT0CXZWBB0\","                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
[7] "         \"types\" : ["                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
[8] "            \"establishment\","                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
[9] "            \"point_of_interest\","                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
[10] "            \"train_station\","                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
[11] "            \"transit_station\""                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
[12] "         ]"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
[13] "      },"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
[14] "      {"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
[15] "         \"geocoder_status\" : \"OK\","                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
[16] "         \"place_id\" : \"ChIJSSKDr7ZC1moRTsSnSV5BnuM\","                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
[17] "         \"types\" : ["                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
[18] "            \"establishment\","                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
[19] "            \"point_of_interest\","                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
[20] "            \"train_station\","                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
[21] "            \"transit_station\""                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
[22] "         ]"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
[23] "      }"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
[24] "   ],"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
[25] "   \"routes\" : ["
... etc
```